# Ignoring leading whitespace with character array in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm using the fgets function to read a line from a file.  I don't understand how to ignore the leading whitespace of a file though.  I thought if I had a char array I could check the first value to see if it is whitespace with isspace, and then increment to the next value.  My code looks like:

```
while (!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(str, LINE_SIZE, fp);
        while (isspace(*str)) {     // need help 
            str + 1;        // here
        }


        for (cp = str; cp = strtok(cp, "AEIOUaeiou\n"); cp = NULL) {
            puts(cp);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you want is something like

```
while (!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(str, LINE_SIZE, fp);
        char * tmp = str; //use a temporary variable so str pointer isn't overwritten
        while (*tmp && isspace(*tmp)) {     // need help 
           tmp++;        // here
        }


        for (cp = tmp; cp = strtok(cp, "AEIOUaeiou\n"); cp = NULL) {
            puts(cp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have (*tmp && isspace (*tmp)) in the while loop?  I understand why you have the isspace, but not the first *tmp.  Thanks!

Comment: @Crystal: if `tmp` is all spaces, then the loop will get to the end of the string - the test for `*tmp` ends the loop when it reaches that point instead of running past the end into undefined memory.

Comment: @Michael: but '\0' is not a space character, so this test is unnecessary.

Comment: @unwind: nice. @Charles: +1 for a good answer.  This code reads the last line twice, btw.

Comment: @unwind: true enough.  Didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 1):

the value of str was not modified. try to change

```
str+1;
```

to

```
str++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
str = str+1;
```

which can be shorten to

```
str += 1;
```

or even better

```
++ str;
```

in `// here` to update the pointer `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues:

Most of the times, you don't want to do the check `feof(fp)` at the top of a loop when reading a file.  It is almost guaranteed that if you do so, you will [read the last line of the file twice](http://c-faq.com/stdio/feof.html).  This is because `feof()` returns true only if an *earlier* read attempt resulted in "end of file".  Better method is to check if `fgets()` returns `NULL`:

```
while (fgets(str, LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
    /* do your processing */
}
if (ferror(fp)) { /* there was an error reading some data */ }
```

---

Your `isspace()` call should cast `*str` to `unsigned char` if it is not of that type:

```
while (isspace((unsigned char)(*str))) {
```

To use `isspace()`, you should `#include <ctype.h>`.

---

You need to increment `str`.  Your expression `str+1` evaluates `str+1`, discards its value, and does nothing.  So, you need:

```
++str;
```

But you don't want to increment `str`: you need that for the next `fgets()` call.  So, you should copy it to a temporary pointer:

```
char *tmp = str;
while (isspace((unsigned char)(*tmp))) {
    ++tmp;
}
```

---

Making all the changes above, your loop becomes:

```
while (fgets(str, LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
    char *tmp = str;
    while (isspace((unsigned char)(*tmp)))
        ++tmp;

    for (cp = tmp; cp = strtok(cp, "AEIOUaeiou\n"); cp = NULL) {
        puts(cp);
    }
}
```

(You have an extra closing `}`, most likely a copy-paste error.)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Kenny and Piere since they have mentioned `str++` and `++str`, the difference between the two is which version of `str` will be used in the expression.

For example

```
int y=1;
x[y++]=10;     //1
and x[++y]=10; //2
```

in `//1` index 1 is used and `x[1]` is assigned 10 and after that `y is 2` and in `//2` `x[2]=10` meaning that y was incremented before it was used as an index.

Generally you want to use `++value` everywhere. However as I have illustrated `value++` has its uses.